# Build failed for Java Ant task in Jenkins

Tags: java, ant, jenkins

I am running ant in Jenkins in Amazon t2.micro Ubuntu instance. Java task failed. Below is my Jenkins console

```
 [java] Compiling module com.eit.manufacturing.displayprocessor.Manufacturing
 [java] Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000ed84e000, 53288960, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
 [java] #
 [java] # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
 [java] # Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 53288960 bytes for committing reserved memory.
 [java] # An error report file with more information is saved as:
 [java] # /root/.jenkins/jobs/Manufacturing Apps/workspace/ManufacturingWeb/hs_err_pid5235.log
```

Here is my ant script:

```
<target
    name="clientcompile"
    depends="servercompile"
    description="GWT compile to JavaScript (production mode)" >

    <java
        classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler"
        failonerror="true"
        fork="true" >
        <classpath>
        <pathelement location="src" />
        <path refid="project.class.path" />
        <pathelement location="${gwt.sdk}\validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar" />
        <pathelement location="${gwt.sdk}\validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar" />
        </classpath>
        <jvmarg value="-Xmx256M" />
        <arg line="-war" />
        <arg value="war" />
        <arg line="${gwt.args}" />
        <arg value="com.eit.manufacturing.displayprocessor.Manufacturing" />
   </java>
</target>
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Well, the thing ran out of memory so maybe you should consider to switch to a slightly bigger instance? We all know that Java needs quite a bit of memory.

Comment: Updated title to add more details and fixed minor formatting issues. As @fvu mentions try to run it in a bigger instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following for the `java` task

`<jvmarg value="-Xmx1g" />`